# How to efficiently add/push elements to an array if not already present

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have one array with the name **produtosSelecionados**.

I need to create one function that every call push the elements **produtosSelecionados** to array **produtosConfirmadosAnuncio**, but the element don't have to push if this element is already in **produtoConfirmadosAnuncio**.

I try something like:

```
adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.produtosSelecionados.length;i++){
      for(let j=i+1;j<this.produtosSelecionados.length;j++){
        if(this.produtosSelecionados[i] !== this.produtosSelecionados[j]){
          this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.push(this.produtosSelecionados[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio);
  }
```

But this way the elements is pushing repetead in my array **produtosConfirmadosAnuncio**. How can I do this?

Comment: What type do elements of your arrays have? There are different rules used to compare primitives and objects https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: Let me know if below is exactly what you are looking for

Comment: You should use includes method specifically if the element already exist in your array

Comment: Use a Set as a data structure, maybe order won't be maintained, but no duplicates will arise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need this code inside your method in place of nested loop.

**Includes** method helps to check if element already exist in an array.

```
if(!yourArray.includes(element){
    yourArray.push(element);
}
```

In your code specifically you need this :

```
adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio(){
    for(let i=0;i<this.produtosSelecionados.length;i++){
        if(!this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.includes(this.produtosSelecionados[i])){
            this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.push(this.produtosSelecionados[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Using for..of**

```
adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio(){
    for(let product of this.produtosSelecionados){
        if(!this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.includes(product)){
            this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.push(product);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use double loop, this affect the effiency of the code. You can do:

```
adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio(){
    for(let producto of this.productosSeleccionados) {
          //indexOf return -1 if the item don't exist in the array
          if(this.productosConfirmadosAnuncio.indexOf(producto) === -1){
            this.productosConfirmadosAnuncio = [
                ...this.productosConfirmadosAnuncio,
                producto
            ]
      }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
For good practices and more effiency use this for add elements instead of push. The method push modify the object, and this is more expensive than assign the variable, like my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
class MyClass {

  constructor() {
    this.produtosSelecionados = [{n:"P1"},{n:"P2"},{n:"P3"}];
    this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio = [];
    this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.push(this.produtosSelecionados[0]) // put p1
  }

  adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio() {   
    this.produtosSelecionados.forEach( 
      p=> this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.includes(p) ? 0 : this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio.push(p) );
    console.log(this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio);
  }

}

let p = new MyClass();
p.adicionaProdutoConfirmadosAnuncio();
```